# Is the set of derivatives of analytic functions of the unit disk equicontinuous?

Tags: complex-analysis, equicontinuity

Let $F$ be the set of analytic functions from the (open) unit disk $\mathbb{D} $ to itself.  Let $G$ be the set of derivative functions of $F$.  I'm trying to show that $G$ is not an equicontinuous family of functions by showing that $G$ contains a sequence of functions that doesn't contain a subsequence that converges to a continuous function, thereby demonstrating that the conclusion of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem fails for $G$.  Since $G$ is a uniformly pointwise bounded family of functions, we would be done.

My suggestion for such a candidate sequence of functions is as follows: Let $f_n(z) = e^{inp}  z$ where $p$ is a positive irrational number and  $n \geq 1$. I conjecture that the sequence of derivatives $f'_n(z) = e^{inp} $  would do the job, but not sure how to prove it.

Comment: Are you asking for equicontinuity on the *entire* disk or for local equicontinuity, i.e. on compact subsets?

Comment: Equicontunity on the disk  $\mathbb{D}$

Comment: Then $f_n(z) = z^n$ should be a counter-example. – Note that even $F$ need not be equicontinuous on the *entire* disk.

Comment: Wouldn't the sequence of functions $z^n$ converge point wise to the 0 function?

Comment: Are you asking for equicontinuity in each point of the disk, or uniform equicontinuity in the disk?

Comment: Point wise equicontinuity,  that is,  for any $\epsilon > 0$ and any $x \in \mathbb{D} $,  there is some $\delta_x > 0$ such that $|f(y) - f(x) | < \epsilon$ whenever $|x-y|<\delta_x$,  as required in the hypothesis of the Arzelà–Ascoli theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cauchy's integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)
for the second derivative
$$
 f''(a)  = \frac{2!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=r} \frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^3} dz \, .
$$
for $|a| < r < 1$
implies that the family $\{ f'' \mid f \in F \}$ of second derivatives
is uniformly bounded on each closed disk $K = \{ z: |z-a| \le \varepsilon \} \subset \Bbb D$.

It follows that the family $G$ of first derivatives
is uniformly equicontinuous on $K$, and in particular equicontinuous
at each point $a \in \Bbb D$.

In your example $f'_n(z) = e^{inp}$ there is a subsequence converging
to the constant $1$, because $np$ comes arbitrarily close to multiples
of $2 \pi$.

Comment: By the same reasoning then  won't $F$ also be uniformly equicontinuous on $\mathbb{D} $?

Comment: @DennisChew: No, it works only on compact subsets of the unit disk (so that you have a lower bound for the denominator in the integral).

Answer (score 0):

By the compactness of the unit circle, there is a subsequence $n_k$ such that $e^{in_k p}$ converges to some $e^{i\theta},$ so your trial balloon is fast losing altitude. I would suggest looking at Montel's theorem.

Comment: Thank you.  But doesn't Montel's theorem require uniform boundedness and  not the weaker uniform pointwise boundedness?

Comment: @DennisChew I'm thinking of this version of Montel: If $f_n$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions on $\mathbb D$ that is uniformly bounded on each compact subset of $\mathbb D,$ then there exists a subsequence $n_k$ such that $D^m(f_{n_k})$ converges  uniformly on compact sets for each $m=0,1,\dots.$ So every sequence in $G$ contains a subsequence that converges uniformly on compact sets, hence converges to a holomorphic function in $\mathbb D.$